# Is there a single word for "The excitement and enthusiasm at the beginning of a new job/romance" etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests

In my native language, there is a single word to express the high energy and enthusiasm shown by many at the beginning of a new job/project/romance etc. Normally it is used with a bit of skepticism/sarcasm.

I am looking for a single word or phrase in English that expresses the same

Comment: A new romance, or any new experience is a *thrill*.

Comment: How about a 'new fling'?

Comment: I would call it "initial enthusiasm".

Comment: Would you accept *Naivety?*

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is your native language; and what is the word?

Comment: My native language is [a local Indian language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayalam). There is a single word which roughly translates to "initial rush" or "beginner's excitement", and also an old saying on the line "new daughter-in-law cleans even the roof corners"

Comment: "Ignorance"? :)

Comment: What's the word in Malayalam, by the way?

Comment: @Kris ആരംഭശൂരത്വം See [here](http://jenson.in/mal2mal.php?word=%E0%B4%86%E0%B4%B0%E0%B4%82%E0%B4%AD%E0%B4%82)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*[Honeymoon](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/honeymoon) period* is often used to refer to this time.

*any new relationship characterized by an initial period of harmony and goodwill.*

Comment: I knew this word existed - but as I understand this is neutral. I am looking for a word which hints already that this is just the beginner's enthusiasm

Comment: @zencv how does it not mean that this is beginners' enthusiams?

Comment: i think it depends on the context - in romance or marriage, "honeymoon period" may mean as a normal phase experienced by all couples. But in a new job, life in a new city etc., I am looking for a word where there is _a bit of an **illusion** that the experience in the "honeymoon period" is everlasting_

Comment: Honeymoon period provides that connotation.

Comment: +1. In my experience, "honeymoon period" strongly implies that this phase will be followed by some degree of disillusionment/disappointment.

Comment: alright, so "Honeymoon period" seems to be the most appropriate and well, popular as well.

Comment: Would you usually say that in a professional context?

Comment: @ArlaudPierre It wouldn't sound out of place in a professional context, and it's a phrase often used by highbrow media (for example the [BBC: Nigeria leader ends honeymoon period](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/africa/7118027.stm): an article about how the energy and enthusiasm for a new (2007) Nigerian president was starting to slip)

Comment: just now i am reading an [article](http://www.businessweek.com/articles/2014-05-22/ibms-eps-target-unhelpful-amid-cloud-computing-challenges#r=read) in BW where "honeymoon" is mentioned - but the usage "The honeymoon proved _short-lived._" reignites my old doubt that the word "honeymoon" itself may not imply the meaning that a happy time is temporary. OK, in this case, may be it could be argued that honeymoon period was even shorter than normal.

Answer (score 17):

[Novelty](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Anovelty) is related, particularly on the "used with a bit of scepticism" point. It typically indicates, if not enthusiasm, some level of interest found in a new and different situation.

> *"My new job is amazing!"*
>
> *"Let's see if you still think that when the novelty's worn off."*

Comment: The appropriate meaning of the feeling called 'novelty' is best brought about only in the expression *when the novelty wears off*.

Comment: @Kris This is true. In fact, I suppose it is often used to express one's own scepticism, rather than excitement or scepticism of another's excitement, at new circumstances. "I'm not sure about my new boyfriend; it's all rather novel."

Comment: @Kris I have used the word *novel* positively. "This is a novel approach." I have also used it neutrally, "They sell novelties," or "It is a novelty item."

Comment: @fredsbend It's common to use *novel* in a positive sense, *novelty* is a different story in its connotations. All the excitement & enthusiasm the OP mentions in the question "is just novelty," wait until the veneer peels off!

Answer (score 14):

**[Limerance](http://scienceray.com/biology/love-its-all-in-the-head/)**: The magic of chemistry that happens in our brains when we fall in love.

> Limerence has also been defined in terms of the potentially
>   inspirational effects and the relationship to attachment theory, **which
>   is not exclusively sexual**, as being "an involuntary potentially
>   inspiring state of adoration and attachment to a limerent object
>   involving intrusive and obsessive thoughts, feelings and behaviors
>   from euphoria to despair, contingent on perceived emotional
>   reciprocation”. -[Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerence)

Answer (score 12):

*Honeymoon period* and *infatuation* are the two terms that spring to my mind.

Comment: Hi Erik, I think that 'honeymoon period' is already top of the list here. :)

Comment: 'infatuation' is a very good suggestion, and expresses the skepticism that the OP seems to be looking for as well as 'honeymoon period' does. +1

Answer (score 8):

The initial [rush](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rush), though often used of drug induced euphoria or an adrenaline surge, can also be used to indicate the *high* of a new job or romance:

> There's no way to fully recreate that new job feeling, but leaders can promote the ingredient that fuels the *rush* of a new job...
>   The *rush* of making a new friend can most definitely be likened to the *rush* of a new romance, things just feel a tad more exciting

Comment: good one, +1 for the examples

Answer (score 3):

In French there is a single word too, and I can find the following translations which are quite close to the idea you wish to convey:

- **[fire in the belly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fire_in_the_belly)**: The emotional stamina and vigor, passion, or inner drive to achieve something, to take action.
- **[elan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elan)**: **ardor** or **zeal** inspired by passion or enthusiasm.
- Also: *oomph*.

Comment: Don't tease us!  Qu'est-ce que c'est?

Comment: The word? I was thinking of « fougue » but it is mostly in a romantic or sexual context.

Answer (score 3):

Infatuation.

Google `infatuation definition` says:

> an intense but short-lived passion or admiration for someone or something.
>   "he had developed an infatuation with the girl"

Answer (score 2):

***Euphoria*** is one word used to describe that intense feeling of happiness and expectation.

> A feeling or state of intense excitement and happiness:
>   *in his euphoria, he had become convinced he could defeat them*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/euphoria?q=euphoria)

Comment: This isn't specific to a particular cause.

Answer (score 1):

The word *[gaga](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gaga)* is about as positive as you can get and sums up your question.

> not thinking clearly because you have very strong feelings of love for
>   someone or because you are very enthusiastic or excited about
>   something
>
> **Usage:**
>   I had a great first date with Dan last night.  I think I am gaga over him.
>
> New boss went gaga over my first few projects, now she expects perfect every time.

Answer (score 1):

The phrases **[love at first sight](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/love%20at%20first%20sight)** and **[at first blush](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/at%20first%20blush)** both convey an initial infatuation that often is tempered by time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the expressions:

> "*Things always look rosy at the beginning*"
>
> "*The future always starts out looking rosy*"
>
> "*Just wait until [novelty wears off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_effect)*"
>
> "*[New brooms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/New+brooms+sweep+clean) sweep clean*"
>
> "*[Everything new](http://blog.artconnectberlin.com/2014/05/09/spotlight-on-porte-renaud/) is fine*"

Answer (score 0):

The word "**[zeal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zeal)**," or "zealousness," often indicates high energy or enthusiasm exerted towards a given activity. While it can be used in positive contexts, it also can be used cynically, as a way to to suggest that someone is *too* enthusiastic but lacks the experience that would give them a more balanced or laid back outlook.

Comment: *Zeal*, however, also indicates long-term commitment. The question was looking for a word that indicates short-term excitement.

Answer (score 0):

smitten, this is probably what your looking for.

Comment: Hi Craiga, welcome to ELU. You could improve you answer with an example usage, especially for using this term in the context of a new job.

Comment: Would you really use this word to describe the excitement of a new job?

Answer (score -1):

Rejuvenation

"to make (someone) feel or look young, healthy, or energetic again"

Answer (score -1):

"Enchant" seems to work in: "John was enchanted by the possibility of being able to redeem himself."

Also, http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enchant  gives us: "to attract and hold the attention of (someone) by being interesting, pretty, etc.", while Google gives us, as the first hit for "enchant", "fill (someone) with great delight; charm."

Comment: I implore you to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to contribute properly to this site. Answers are expected to provide some amount of explanation, including suitable references and links.

Comment: This suggestion might actually work, but because you have a track record of answering questions  with a single response this suggestion might get deleted. Why not explain why you think this word fits? Provide a link to a dictionary that backs up your guess. How hard is it?

Comment: Or simply leave _enchantment_ as a comment, if you're not willing to elaborate. Plus, as this thread clearly shows, there is no "single word". Your whole "The single word is:" preface seems like weak lead-in created solely to reach the required character count.

Comment: @choster: Thank you for your critique. Having thought the answer was self-explanatory, I didn't see the need to provide  corroborating links.  However, I'm new to this site so I'll visit the help center and peruse the rules so as not to run afoul of the "law" again. ;)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Thank you for your critique.  Of course your suggestions are easily realizable, but "guess" and "How hard is it" seem more like unwarranted pejorative slaps than genuinely constructive criticism.

Comment: You've said more in one reply than in several answers you have posted. Good to see you are capable of arguing a case :)

Comment: @J.R.: Thank you for your critique, and - Bingq! - you hit the nail right on the head!  Having been apprised by the system that single word answers are unacceptable, (unless, of course, the single word is at least 30 characters long)  even though that's what was asked for,  I endeavored to find a way to present my single-word answer cleanly and understandably.  I seem to have accomplished my goal, much to the chagrin of those who would have me prove the validity of my contribution rather than their having to disprove it.  Oh, well... into each life a little rain must fall. :-)

Comment: @EM: You could try something like, "One word that might work is:" or "Another possible word to consider would be:". You could also take a page from Andrew Leach's answer, and paste something from the page of a dictionary. Even better, use it in a sample sentence that fits the O.P. context: _Now that I've been at my job for six weeks, the initial euphoria of being employed again is starting to wear off._ (If you have trouble thinking of a really good sentence, then maybe your suggested word isn't such a good word after all.) In any case, instead of bitching about the weather, hit the EDIT link.

Comment: @JR: Your first two suggestions are just variations on the: "Use enough fill to get over the minimum character hump" scheme I used, which you pooh-poohed, so I'm surprised you'd offer them up as if they came from your camp and, only because of that, are acceptable. Linking to a dictionary page is OK, but I like the "sample sentence" approach best; maybe I'll use it next time. BTW, why the attitude?

Comment: @EM - Truthfully, I wanted to soften the last sentence of my previous comment, but I was running out of characters. I don't mean to have an "attitude", nor give a "critique"; my comments are meant to be helpful _teach-a-man-to-fish_ suggestions for down the road. The difference between my two "filler" suggestions and yours is that yours could be construed to mean that there is one (and only one) "right" word (and therefore the other suggestions are inferior), whereas mine are phrased in a way that implies other options may be equally valid (or maybe even superior).

Comment: @JR I appreciate your stated position with regard to attitude, but it occurs to me that my use of hyperbole being equated to "bitching about the weather" is not only inaccurate but bears none of the hallmarks associated with the altruism of teaching a man to fish.

Comment: The weather comment was an allusion to "Oh, well... into each life a little rain must fall."

Comment: @JR: Indeed it was, but being sorely bereft of acknowledgement of its slightly amusing blatantly allegorical nature, there seems to be no charity in your nature.  In addition, altruism certainly isn't your wont, so what is it you're trying to accomplish with your banter?